# Trying to find fourth root and keep getting overflow error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the fourth root of k using newton raphson's method. I keep getting an overflow error.

I looked for solutions online like import decimal but I have not learned any of the solutions offered in class

```
epsilon = 0.01

k = 100.0

guess = k/2.0

while abs(guess**4 - k) >= epsilon:

    guess = guess -(((guess**4) -k)/(4*guess))

print ('Square root of', k, 'is about', guess)
```

OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
In while loop statement

Comment: Your maths is off. Your first equation resolves to `(while abs(6250000 - 100) >= 0.01:)` and then `guess = guess -(((guess**4) -k)/(4*guess))` resolves to -31199 which overshoots your epsilon 0.01 by quite a bit.....

Comment: Your denominator is far too small; the first derivitive of `n**4` is not `4*n`, but `4*n**3`.

Comment: Ohhhh the derivative is wrong. Gotta brush up on my calculus

Answer (score 0):

A fast-converging algorithm for n-th root of a number can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm). It also shows how the algorithm is derived from the Newton-Raphson method.

This would translate to following python code:

```
# Accuracy
epsilon = 0.01

# Calc 4th root
n = 4  

# Number to take n-th root of
num = 100.0  

# Inital guess
guess = num/2.0 

# Initial delta 
delta = 1/n * (num/guess**(n-1) - guess)

while abs(delta) >= epsilon:
    delta = 1/n * (num/guess**(n-1) - guess)
    guess += delta


print(f'Square root of {num} is about {guess}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Square root of 100.0 is about 3.162277698738321
```